# Three-column fluid footer that will shrink to min-width then drop to next line

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, fluid-layout

I would like 3 divs next to each other that evenly fill their containing div. As the screen is resized I would like the divs to begin shrinking until their min-width is reached. Only when each has reached their min-width should they drop to the next line.

I have tried several options including inline-block floats to left and right with another div in the middle, but just cannot get what I am looking for.

Here is a fiddle of what I currently have: http://jsfiddle.net/mN9qx/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="footer">
  <div id="address">Bobs Consulting, LLC<br />1234 Oak Street<br /> Union City, NV 122345 </div>   
  <div id="terms">Privacy Statement<br />
  Terms and Conditions<br />
  Copyright 2014.
  </div>
  <div id="def">A bunch of text here. The text should not wrap or condense when the screen resizes.</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#footer {
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:10px;
color:#777;
height:60px;
}

#footer div {
float:left; 
height:50px;
max-width:220px;
width:33%;
padding: 10px 0px 0px 20px;
margin: -1px 0px 0px -1px;
border:1px solid;
border-color:#aaa;
}

#address { min-width:120px; }
#terms { min-width:140px; }
#def { min-width:220px; }
```

I would like an html/css solution. A media query is also acceptable. I can do it with flexbox, but I want something that is as widely supported as possible.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT:** I have fallen back to the flexbox technique and have decided not to support older browsers. Browsers that do not support flexbox will display a vertical stack instead of horizontal. The addition of a float:left will display as horizontal in older browsers. Flexbox code can be seen in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mN9qx/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Jua3/):

```
<html>

<head>
    <style type='text/css'>
        body
        {
            width:100%;
        }

        .footer
        {
            float:left;
            width:33%;
            height:100px;
            min-width:50px;
            background:#ff0000;
            margin:1px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="footer"></div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The problem here is that each of my footer columns has a different min-width. Once the edge or min-width of the right most div is reached, it drops to the next line. I want the other two to continue to shrink before the right div drops. Is this even possible with css?

Comment: in my code, all three shrink until the minimum width is reached, which answers the "I want the other two to continue to shrink before the right div drops" - unless you are not explaining it well, how you want it to appear. I updated the jsfiddle to include varying minimum widths: http://jsfiddle.net/7Jua3/1/

Comment: I am sorry I am not explaining it very well. In your jsfiddle, I observe all three divs shrinking as the window is reduced. Before the footer3 div hits its min-width, it drops below the first div. All three continue to shrink until footer3 hits its min. The others continue to shrink until they hit their min. What I want is that footer3 will not drop, whether it has hit its min or not, until all the excess space has been used in the divs. In other words, all must hit their min-widths before footer3 drops. I am trying to hold a single row of divs as long as possible before dropping to next row.

Comment: I do understand now what you're looking for. I'm hoping this one is close enough - could be tweaked to be perfect I think.  take 3 - http://jsfiddle.net/7Jua3/2/

Comment: Reducing the width % certainly helps, but it doesn't fit with the rest of my design. I have been tweaking for some time now and have come to the conclusion this is not quite possible with CSS2 features. I have fallen back to a flexbox solution (described in edit at top). As your solution was the closest to my original request, I have marked it as the solution. Thanks very much for your help Geoff.

Comment: no problem, sorry it couldn't do exactly what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:  **[LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/mN9qx/2/)**

CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
#footer * {
    clear:both;
    float:none;
    width:100%;.
    display:block;
}    
}
```

You can adjust the footer div's for any screen size according to your need with the help of media query. Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks, but this is not quite the effect i am looking for. I want the left and middle divs to begin shrinking before the right div drops to the next line. Only when the min-width of all have been reached should the divs begin to drop.